# Node.js Environment Variable configure for windows and Linux

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am developing a Node.js application on Windows 10. But I will deploy my application in a Linux server. I am trying to follow the good practices of Node.js application development.

One of the good practices is separating the system variables like PORT, HOST, debug_logic out of source code and provide these as environment variables while deploying.

How can I achieve following features of my application?

1. Develop application in Windows 10 and deploy in Linux server and provide the environment variable easily
2. Want to debug while the application is developing and stop debugging while deploying using an environment variable.

I add the following script under package.json scripts key.

```
"start": "set \"PORT=80\" & set \"HOST=localhost\" & node server.js"
```

This is kind of working now. But I have a lot more environment variables to work in the future and moreover, I have to do that for Linux also.

I also know that this can be achieved using a .env file and tried that using dotenv module and didn't like the module either.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ow I forget to mention, I also tried this npm package but it seems this has issues in windows cmd.

Comment: Well what *are* those issues? Maybe ask a specific question (or raise an issue on their repo) about that. Or expand on exactly what *"didn't like"* means. Or just use the Linux subsystem for dev.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env to setup environment variables, e.g.:

```
"start": "cross-env \"PORT=80\" & cross-env \"HOST=localhost\" & node server.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where containerization come to place. You can use [docker](https://docs.docker.com/) as it's separate Operating System from application. You can know how to install docker for windows from [this link here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/). I'll let you know how to get started.

Add the following `Dockerfile` in you project root:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN npm init -y
RUN npm install express
```

also add the `docker-compose.yml`  in the same directory:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - /path/to/local/app:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
    - DEBUG=1
    - PORT=3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: node server.js
```

as you can see the key `environment` can hold all variables that you want to hold throw your app.
Once you finished run in the app root: `docker-compose up -d` and check `http://localhost:3000`

Docker can be installed and deployed in both windows and Linux. You can check out the documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks @MED , I have gone through docker container. It would be a wise decision to learn Docker asap.  I have another query for you. If I use 3/4 node modules like express, mongoose, socket.io, do I need to add all modules into to Dockerfile? Is there any way of installing all modules using a single command?

Comment: You will include it in Dockerfile as well, all in one line `RUN npm install express mongoose socket.io` and if you needed to add new module in the middle of your work. You can add in the same line then run `docker-compose build` to add & install the new module then run it normally with `docker-compose up`